# Why does this code have two different results?

Tags: javascript

```
var addCount;
function s1() {
    var count = 0;
    addCount = function() {
        count++;
    };
    function s12() {
        console.log(count)
    }
    return s12
}
var result1 = s1();
var result2 = s1();
addCount();
result1(); // count = 0;
result2(); // count = 1;
```

[In the picture I marked the puzzled place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klG3m.png)
Then, the next step will be shown in this way
[This is where I am really puzzled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vK5o.png)

Comment: After each call to s1, addCount refers to the count variable referenced in the closure created by that call.  So addCount() when called references the count variable in the closure referenced by result2

Comment: This is being discussed in the answers, but I want to draw it plainly to your (Rodney_Dian) attention: The answer you've accepted is incorrect and will confuse your understanding further. You can prove that it's wrong by adding more calls to `result1()` and `result2()` at the end of your code. You'll find that no matter how many times or in what order you call them, every call to `result1()` returns 0 and every call to `result2()` returns 1.  (Unless you call `addCount()` again, which will further increase `result2()` while leaving `result1()` still at 0.) Read other answers below to see why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `result` is a function that is declared as being the result of calling the `s1` function. Calling `s1` returns the `s12` function and that function uses a variable called `count` which is declared at a higher level (scope) than itself (this is called a "free variable").

When a free variable is used inside of a function that has a lifetime that is longer than the function where the free variable was declared, a **["closure"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)** is created around that free variable and it stays in scope even after the function it was declared in terminates.

When you call `result` the first time, `count` increases by one and that value stays in memory so that when you call it a second time, you are working with the last value.

Comment: @Rodney_Dian You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote and mark as the answer.

Comment: Calling `result` (I guess you mean `result1` or `result2`) doesn't increase `count`.

Comment: Call `result1`.  Then call `result2`  Then go back and call `result1` again.  Pretty soon you'll notice patterns of behavior that cannot be explained by @ScottMarcus 's explanation... because it's incorrect yet sadly attracting up-votes and acceptance.  Multiple answers below have the facts correct (unlike this one).  OP should accept one of them (whether or not it's mine, though I believe mine is most complete).

Comment: The accepted answer here is not correct. Please see @MarkAdelsberger s answer to see what's really going on in OP's code.

Answer (score 5):

To understand this behavior, you need to really understand what closures do.  The short (but probably confusing if you aren't really in tune with closures) answer is this:

Each invocation of `s1` does the following:

**A) Create a variable named count and initialize it to 0**

This seems straightforward enough...

**B) Create a function that increments the variable from (A), and set the `addCount` variable to point to it**

Some important details are hidden here.  The variable this function will update is *the one created in step (A) of **the same invocation** of `s1`.*  This is a consequence of the closure mechanism.

Of course when the 2nd invocation of `s1` reaches this step, it overwrites the value of `addEvent`, replacing the function that increments the `count` created by the prior invocation of `s1` with a new function that increments the `count` created by this current invocation of `s1`.

**C) Create and return a function that logs the value of the variable created in (A)**

As with (B), this function too sees the variable created by step A *of the current invocation of `s1`.*

**So what does that mean?**

Well, you call `s1` once and it creates a variable, with value 0, and returns a function that logs that variable (which function you've stored as `result1`).

As a side effect, that call had set `addCount` to a function that would change the value of the variable logged by `result1` if you called it... but you don't call it.

Instead you call `s1` again, which replaces `addCount` with a new function that updates a new variable (also initialized to 0).  It returns a function that logs this new variable, which you store as `result2`.

Now you make a call through `addCount`, which invokes the *second* function updating the *second* variable.  Then you call `result1` logging the first variable (which was never updated), and then you call `result2` logging the second variable (which you incremented once).

Answer (score 1):

Is because variable `addCount` has global scope.

Comment: I guess I wouldn't say that this is wrong, but it certainly makes some odd assumptions about where the understanding gap would be

Answer (score 0):

When running the function `s1` twice, you generate two variables with the name count, each in the scope of the current method call.

Other than that, your `addCount` method is global for both calls. Your second call overrides the first one.

So in the new `addCount` method, you have the scope of your second `s1` call.

Thus, your call to `addCount` has the second `count` variable in scope and increments this one.

When printing your results you go back to both scopes and get the correct values of `count = 0` in the scope of your first call and `count = 1` in the scope of your second.

Comment: You don't generate two variables named `count`. There is a closure around the single `count` variable and both invocations of the function share it. You can't have two identically named entities both declared in the same scope. If you did, the last one declared would overwrite the earlier one. Once the value changes from 1 to 2, there is no going back and getting the 1 again.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - You are mistaken.  The variables are **not** shared, as this example demonstrates.  Closures are all about going back and getting the 1 again; that is *exactly* what they do.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger No, you are mistaken. Closures are all about shared scope of free variables. The fix for unintended closure consequences is to create separate scopes by either making a copy of the variable or creating dedicated scopes (say, with `let`).

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger What's throwing you off here is that `addCount()` is delcared globally.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - Nope.  I'm not "thrown off".  Your explanation is wrong, which is why you have to retreat to cookie cutter solutions when you don't understand what's happening.  In OP's code, there are absolutely two variables (each called `count` within its scope) created by two calls to `s1`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - What's throwing you off is that you misunderstand what `let` does.  It only makes a difference when there are blocks within a function, which can become scopes using `let`.  But even with simple old `var`, the function is already its own scope for variables.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I am not thrown off, nor am I resorting to "cookie cutter" anything. Your explanation of the overall execution of the code is correct, but your statement that closures *"all about going back and getting the 1 again"* is absolutely wrong. Closures (as I correctly stated) are all about sharing scope (so that you don't have multiple values) and I understand perfectly well what `let` is and how it works. The conclusion you incorrectly jumped to was that I was simply recommended changing `var` to `let`, which I was not. I mentioned it as a way to create a block scope where.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - That's nice.  You still explicitly claimed that the multiple calls to `s1` share a `count` variable, which they don't.  I could explain why the rest of my "assumptions" aren't assumptions, and are in fact correct, but until you can reconcile your answer with the reality that the two calls each create a separate variable, none of the rest matters.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - Okay. So why are there two different values of `count` printed without changing the value of `count` between the two calls? If it was a shared variable it should print the same value two times ..